# CrystalReportViewer is not displayed in a aspx page

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I show you the following screenshots.

Development environment is: Windows 8.1, Visual Studio 2013, .net 4.5, localhost.

*Display in google chrome*
[image: Execution in browser]

*test.aspx Design*
[image: web page Design]

I tried this solution but has not walked.

I included this folder `crystalreportviewers13` in my projet.

And i added The following line in Web.Config.

```
<configSections>
 <sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
 <sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
 <section name="printControl" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
 </sectionGroup>
 </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

Comment: Try this and check : Open your report in visual studio, Go to Design and Page Setup, uncheck the CheckBox "No Printer"

Comment: Not walked :( thank you for your answer

Comment: Have you tried in a different browser?

Comment: In chrome and Firefox not walked but in Internet Explorer i have this warning:

`Unhandled exception at line 60, column 3 in http://localhost:3199/test

0x800a1391 - JavaScript execution error "bobj" is undefined`

Comment: Please go through this page. There they discuss many causes for this problem. http://tektutorialshub.com/crystal-report-shows-a-blank-page/

Comment: I tried it and did not work but I will try again